# Stop microsoft teams from automaticaly booting up

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using Microsoft teams on Ubuntu 18.04 and don't want it to automatically pop up when I boot up my computer. I couldn't find any information about this on the internet. I hoping somebody can help me.

Comment: [See answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).  Then disable team from starting at login using the appropriate software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable auto-startup of Microsoft Teams in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254225/how-to-disable-auto-startup-of-microsoft-teams-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Open up Teams->Settings, uncheck '**Auto-start application**' and '**On close, keep the application running**'.
[Screenshot of Teams settings to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G65ZA.png)

Then open up **Startup Applications** in Ubuntu and remove the Microsoft Teams startup on login.

Answer (score 0):

Find the Startup Applications control with the Dashboard.

[image: Dialog box for Startup Applications]

Click on the button to the right labeled Remove.

See if that works for you.

Comment: You can also uncheck the box next to it rather than remove the entry. This way if you change your mind later, you can check the box again.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This does not work. Teams adds it to the list once again.