# Microsoft Teams can't be disabled on startup

Tags: 20.04, microsoft-teams

After following
[Stop microsoft teams from automaticaly booting up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314170/stop-microsoft-teams-from-automaticaly-booting-up?rq=1) my teams app will still start at startup. I've also looked in /etc/xdg but haven't found any file related to the app.

Using the official Microsoft release and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please clarify only 1 problem at once , This in not a question but questions "_"

Comment: @Algnis My bad ! Edited it to focus on the first problem

Comment: Ah sorry @Archismal Panigrahi ... I didn't see your comment before I answered. Your previous answer works well! I'd managed to work it out for myself hence answering here but I've upvoted your previous answer as it is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent it automatically starting by deselecting that from *within teams*.

Open Teams.

Click on the three dots near the top right (next to your initials in a circle).

[image]

That opens up the settings menu ... in 'General', there's a box you can tick / untick 'Auto-start application' - if you deselect that, it won't auto start when you boot. Works for me in 20.04.3 LTS.

[image]
Select

Comment: Thanks ! It seems like my question was a duplicate, but my first search didn't find it.